# Create rest api on java - reverse endpoints

Tags: java, rest, api

I am creating a rest api on java and I got a problem that users will have to poll my REST URL often to get changes in data. But then I think what if I will send them a special REST call to their server to notify for changes? It will be not a good api because they will have to have their procession points, etc. How to resolve this situation?

Comment: Pushing data to clients would be preferred over them polling endlessly

Comment: Thanks, I think so too. But is it a good practice or kinda a noob solution?

Comment: That's what Firebase does... Seems like a good practice, if possible to implement reasonably

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you are not using the right tool for the job. REST over HTTP may not suit your needs.

Have you considered Server-Sent Events (SSE) or even WebSockets? They may fit your needs better.

Comment: Thanks, but websockets and SSE are difficult to set up for clients. REST is more suitable I think